# For a 1 to 1 relationship in Django, do the 2 models share ids?

Tags: python, django, django-models

If I have model that has a 1 to 1 relationship with another, do they share primary ids? Thank you.

Comment: I just read your question again. I really hope you didn't mean to ask if `ModelA` and `ModelB` share the same primary key, because I'm sure you can see why that's a horrible idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely not.

> `OneToOneField` classes used to automatically become the primary key on
>   a model. This is no longer true (although you can manually pass in the
>   `primary_key` argument if you like). Thus, it's now possible to have
>   multiple fields of type `OneToOneField` on a single model.

*Source:* https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#one-to-one-relationships